# Angular reactive form disabled input field

Tags: angular

I have a component with a reactive form

```
  form = this.fb.group({
    fullname: this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      lastName: '',
    }),
    income: this.fb.group({
      preTax: '',
      annualIncome: { value: '', disabled: true },
    }),
    job: '',
    realName: false,
  });
```

Although the annualIncome field is disabled i haved binded to a method that returns a number

```
<input 
      formControlName="annualIncome" 
      [value]="calculateAnnualIncome(form.value.income.preTax)"
      type="text" 
      class="form-control">
```

The method called is:

```
  calculateAnnualIncome(preTax) {
    return preTax * 14 * ((100 - 21) / 100);
  }
```

Although i see the value in the field when i am trying to retrieve it it returns ""

```
console.log(this.form.get('income.annualIncome').value)

output: ""
```

How can i receive the actual value of the field?

Comment: have you tried to subscribe to the field value ? like 

this.form.get('income.annualIncome').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
   consonle.log("income",val);
  });

Answer (score 2):

In your .ts ,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form.controls["income.annualIncome"].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
       console.log(value);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular if you want to get all the values including disabled controls you should use:

```
this.form.getRawValue();
```

Or another way to make it **Readonly** instead of **disabled**. This way you you can get value of that control as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like listening to the **valueChanges** using Observable, you can use **patchValue()** method  to set the value of the disabled field like this.

```
calculateAnnualIncome(preTax){
  let output = preTax * 14 * ((100 - 21) / 100);
  this.income.patchValue({annualIncome:output});
  console.log("Value from Input Filed",this.income.controls.annualIncome.value)

}
```

and you can access the value of the disable field using

```
this.income.controls.annualIncome.value //output:13404.720000000001
```

Or

```
this.form.get('income.annualIncome').value
```

I've solved your problem in a different way, have a look at this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4tcfq)